# Segmentation fault only when running on multi-core

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, multicore

I am using a c++ library that is meant to be multi-threaded and the number of working threads can be set using a variable. The library uses pthreads. The problem appears when I run the application ,that is provided as a test of library, on a quad-core machine using 3 threads or more. The application exits with a segmentation fault runtime error. When I try to insert some tracing "cout"s in some parts of library, the problem is solved and application finishes normally.
When running on single-core machine, no matter what number of threads are used, the application finishes normally.

How can I figure out where the problem seam from?

Is it a kind of synchronization error? how can I find it? is there any tool I can use too check the code ?

Comment: From your description it seems to be a racing condition, where one of the threads is most probably trying to access memory that is not initialized yet by another thread. You might want to try reproing this under the debugger and looking at the call stack at the failure point.

Comment: I really have no idea where the failure point is, because in debug mode the problem does not appear.

Comment: some compilers in the debugging mode initializes the variables  by their default values so it may not happen in the debugging mode

Comment: You can include debugging symbols when optimizing and can attach a debugger regardless of either of those.  "Debug mode" is a misnomer.

Comment: I did not mean debugging options by debug mode, I meant when I do debug the program, the error just don't show itself.

Comment: Valgrind! Valgrind! Valgrind!

Comment: When you get a SEGFAULT you can get the system to dump a core of the program that can then be loaded by the debugger. Different system uses different methods to signal the need for a core file. But usually it is as simple as setting an environment variable. Check your system documentation for details.

Comment: When it comes to threading issues in general and racing in particular it is a pain to track down since attaching a debugger causes the program to behave differently. This makes this particular problem one of the most difficult to find and fix. It also explains that if you enter cout's etc that it then works because I/O normally is rather slow in comparison with normal code and could cancel out the racing condition.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're using Linux (you mention pthreads).  Have you considered running [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Valgrind has tools for checking for data race conditions (helgrind) and memory problems (memcheck).  Valgrind may be to find such an error in debug mode without needing to produce the crash that release mode produces.

Comment: I've used helgrind. it suggests some errors as race conditions in sections that are run in serial sections of code
also it indicates some identical errors in parallel parts as shown below, but I don't understand what it means.

--------------------------------------------
==28556==  This conflicts with a previous read of size 4 by thread #6
==28556==    at 0x806A3ED: Population::GaSortedGroup::GetAt(int) const (SortedGroup.h:181)
.....(order of method calls)

Comment: A race condition is where you have two or more threads looking at the same bit of data at (potentially) the same time.  Generally shared mutable data should be protected by a mutex so you can't (for example) get one thread reading data as another thread updates it.  This can give you stale data and lead to problems.

Answer (score 0):

Some general debugging recommendations.

1. Make sure your build has symbols (compile with -g).  This option is orthogonal to other build options (i.e. the decision to build with symbols is independent of the optimization level).
2. Once you have symbols, take a close look at the call stack of where the seg fault occurs.  To do this, first make sure your environment is configured to generate core files (ulimit -c unlimited) and then after the crash, load the program/core in the debugger (gdb /path/to/prog /path/to/core).  Once you know what part of your code is causing the crash, that should give you a better idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: I know nothing about what core is. and I don't know /path/to/core. could you explain more detailed please?

Comment: Well, you will soon discover 'gdb' then :)

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a race condition.
Where multiple threads are interacting on the same resource.
There are a whole host of possible culprits, but without the source anything we say is a guess.

You want to create a core file; then debug the application with the core file. This will set up the debugger to the state of the application at the point it crashed. This will allow you to examin the variables/registers etc.

How to do this will very depending on your system.

A quick Google revealed this:

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-299035.html

Hope this helps.